# How to avoid error while using list_display in django

Tags: python, django, listview, django-models, django-forms

I need to get view of table in admin.
I imported table from Mysql. In models.py code is written:

```
class Stations2(models.Model):
    id_stations = models.IntegerField(db_column='ID_stations', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    name = models.TextField(db_column='Name', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    type = models.TextField(db_column='Type', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    country = models.TextField(db_column='Country', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    latitude = models.FloatField(db_column='Latitude', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    longitude = models.FloatField(db_column='Longitude', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    elevation = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    site_gaw_id = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    stations_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'stations_2'
```

I wrote in admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Stations2


class data_admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Stations2
    list_display = ('Name', 'Type',)

admin.site.register(Stations2,data_admin)
```

and got an error:

```
ERRORS:
<class 'scrapping_2.admin.data_admin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[0]' refers to 'Name', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'data_admin', or an attribute or method on 'scrapping_2.Stations2'.
<class 'scrapping_2.admin.data_admin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[1]' refers to 'Type', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'data_admin', or an attribute or method on 'scrapping_2.Stations2'.
```

without data_admin code work well. How Should I solve my problem?

Comment: attribute names are case sensitive

Comment: Do you mean,that changing name TableView from data_admin will change th situation?

Comment: ('Name', 'Type',)

Comment: THank you very much!!!!!